# Batch - findstr special characters

Tags: string, batch-file, character

I try to find and move all files with the character "{" (without the quotes) for example `filename{{xyz}}.txt`

**My Code:**

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "source=C:\Users\OLD\*.txt"
set "target=C:\Users\NEW"
set "searchString=}"

set "found="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    findstr /m /i /l /c:"%searchString%" "%source%" 2^>nul 
') do (
    if not defined found set "found=1"
    move "%%a" "%target%"
)

if not defined found (
    echo not found
)
```

This script found all characters, unfortunately not that one what I need `{`. 
So now I will ask here for help.

Best regs

Comment: `dir /B "%source%" | findstr /m /i /l /c:"%searchString%"` to search in file _names_

Comment: Why not just move them direct - `move "*{{*}}.txt" test.txt`. `*` is any or none sequence of characters. `?` is a single character. or if really only 3 characters between brackets `move "*{{???}}.txt" test.txt`

Comment: Are you intending to look for `}` in the file name? Or within the content of the file? Your code is looking at the file content.

Comment: Now I use `move` like "Noodles" suggest. Thx @ all